# How to retrieve a word in a string from an array of possible words

Tags: php, string

I hope I worded the question correctly! I want to retrieve the name of a country if it exists within a string.

```
$bio = 'A biography about someone from France';
$countries = ['Germany', 'Spain', 'France'];
```

How could I check for the existence of a country in the string using the countries array?
And then, if a match is found, return it? In this example, I'd be left with the word France.

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Answer (score 5):

try this code:

```
print_r(array_intersect(explode(' ', $bio), $countries));
```

or

```
foreach ($countries as $v)
    if (mb_stripos($bio, $v) !== false)
    {
        echo $v;
        break;
    }
```

or

```
echo @array_shift(array_intersect(explode(' ', $bio), $countries));
```

Comment: I was just looking for something like this.... Thx!

Answer (score 0):

u have to use foreach on ur countries array, and inside check if strpos(bio, country) to find the position of the country word. if the position is not false it means it's there!!